# Tikz – Box/frame arround Text with interruption

Tags: tikz-pgf, box

does somebody know a trick for creating a box/frame lite this around a text like this:
[image]
I guess it could be working best with `tikz`. Here is the code for the text (without frame):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{3cm}
\begin{center}
{\fontsize{25}{10} \sffamily \color{black!45} Name xy}

\vspace{.5cm}
{\fontsize{75}{10} \sffamily \color{red} 2019}

\vspace{.5cm}
{\fontsize{25}{10} \sffamily \color{black!45} Name}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this? The vertical distances are controlled by `inner ysep`, and the horizontal ones by `inner xsep`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\bfseries]
 \node[scale=4,red!60,inner xsep=1.5ex,inner ysep=0.5ex] (2019){2019};
 \node[above,scale=2,gray!50] at (2019.north) (A) {Name xy};
 \node[below,scale=2,gray!50] at (2019.south) (B) {Name};
 \draw[thick,gray!50] (A.east) -| (2019.east|-B) -- (B.east)
 (A.west) -| (2019.west|-B) -- (B.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: exactly like this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: how about this? `\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\bfseries]
\path 
node[scale=2,violet,draw=gray!50,line width=2pt,rounded corners, inner xsep=2mm,inner ysep=2mm] (2019) {2019}
(2019.north) node[orange,fill=white] {TikZ}
(2019.south) node[orange,fill=white] {texSE};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: @BlackMild Thanks! This also works for white backgrounds. It won't look good if the thing is put on a non-white background, though.

Comment: I just modified from your code. For colored background, say, pink, then just put [fill=pink]. Still there is a problem: I can not adjust texSE in the middle of boundary of the node `2019`.

Comment: @BlackMild You can do `\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\bfseries]
 \path node[scale=4,red,inner xsep=1.5ex,inner ysep=2ex,draw=black!45,thick] 
 (2019){2019} 
 (2019.north) node[scale=2,text=black!45,fill=white,text depth=0pt] {Name xy}
 (2019.south) node[scale=2,text=black!45,fill=white,text depth=0pt]  {Name};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` but why? It only works for monochrome backgrounds.

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun a Ti*k*Z-less version, that only uses `xcolor` and `grabbox` (`grabbox` wouldn't really be necessary, but this way you can use `\verb` and stuff in the braced arguments).

Argument structure of `\boxtext` is:

- optional argument specifying fixed width of top-text
- mandatory argument for top-text
- optional argument specifying fixed width of main-text
- mandatory argument for main-text
- optional argument specifying fixed width of bottom-text
- mandatory argument for bottom-text

If you don't specify a fixed width the natural width is used, if a fixed width is specified the contents will be centred using `\centering`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{grabbox}

\makeatletter
\colorlet{boxtextborder}{gray}
\newlength\toptextpad
\newlength\maintextpad
\newlength\bottomtextpad
\newlength\boxtextborder
\setlength\toptextpad{2pt}
\setlength\maintextpad{5pt}
\setlength\bottomtextpad{2pt}
\setlength\boxtextborder{.4pt}
\newlength\boxtext@maxwd
\newsavebox\boxtext@toptext
\newsavebox\boxtext@maintext
\newsavebox\boxtext@bottomtext
\def\myfi@Tb\fi#1#2#3{\fi#2}
\newcommand\boxtext@ifrelax[1]
  {%
    \ifx\relax#1%
      \myfi@Tb
    \fi
    \@secondoftwo
  }
\newcommand\boxtext[1][\relax]
  {%
    \boxtext@ifrelax{#1}
      {\@grabbox{}\boxtext@toptext{\color{boxtextborder}}\hbox}
      {\@grabbox{\hsize#1\centering}\boxtext@toptext{\color{boxtextborder}}\vbox}%
    {}\boxtext@a
  }
\newcommand\boxtext@a[1][\relax]
  {%
    \boxtext@ifrelax{#1}
      {\@grabbox{}\boxtext@maintext{}\hbox}
      {\@grabbox{\hsize#1\centering}\boxtext@maintext{}\vbox}%
    {}\boxtext@b
  }
\newcommand\boxtext@b[1][\relax]
  {%
    \boxtext@ifrelax{#1}
      {\@grabbox{}\boxtext@bottomtext{\color{boxtextborder}}\hbox}
      {\@grabbox{\hsize#1\centering}\boxtext@bottomtext{\color{boxtextborder}}\vbox}%
    {}\boxtext@out
  }
\newcommand*\boxtext@siderule
  {%
    \vrule
      height
        \dimexpr
          \ht\boxtext@maintext+.5\ht\boxtext@toptext+.5\dp\boxtext@toptext
          +\toptextpad+\maintextpad+.5\boxtextborder
        \relax
      depth
        \dimexpr
          \dp\boxtext@maintext+.5\ht\boxtext@bottomtext+.5\dp\boxtext@bottomtext
          +\maintextpad+\bottomtextpad+.5\boxtextborder
        \relax
      width \boxtextborder
    \relax
  }
\newcommand*\boxtext@toprule
  {%
    \vrule
      width
        \dimexpr
          (\boxtext@maxwd-\wd\boxtext@toptext)/2-\toptextpad
        \relax
      height
        \dimexpr
          \ht\boxtext@maintext+.5\ht\boxtext@toptext+.5\dp\boxtext@toptext
          +\toptextpad+\maintextpad+.5\boxtextborder
        \relax
      depth
        -\dimexpr
          \ht\boxtext@maintext+.5\ht\boxtext@toptext+.5\dp\boxtext@toptext
          +\toptextpad+\maintextpad-.5\boxtextborder
        \relax
    \relax
  }
\newcommand*\boxtext@bottomrule
  {%
    \vrule
      width
        \dimexpr
          (\boxtext@maxwd-\wd\boxtext@bottomtext)/2-\bottomtextpad
        \relax
      height
        -\dimexpr
          \dp\boxtext@maintext+.5\ht\boxtext@bottomtext+.5\dp\boxtext@bottomtext
          +\maintextpad+\bottomtextpad-.5\boxtextborder
        \relax
      depth
        \dimexpr
          \dp\boxtext@maintext+.5\ht\boxtext@bottomtext+.5\dp\boxtext@bottomtext
          +\maintextpad+\bottomtextpad+.5\boxtextborder
        \relax
    \relax
  }
\newcommand*\boxtext@out
  {%
    \mbox
      {%
        \begingroup
        \ifdim\wd\boxtext@maintext>\wd\boxtext@toptext
          \ifdim\wd\boxtext@maintext>\wd\boxtext@bottomtext
            \boxtext@maxwd\wd\boxtext@maintext
          \else
            \boxtext@maxwd\wd\boxtext@bottomtext
          \fi
        \else
          \ifdim\wd\boxtext@toptext>\wd\boxtext@bottomtext
            \boxtext@maxwd\wd\boxtext@toptext
          \else
            \boxtext@maxwd\wd\boxtext@bottomtext
          \fi
        \fi
        \advance\boxtext@maxwd2\maintextpad
        \color{boxtextborder}%
        \boxtext@siderule
        \rlap{\makebox[\boxtext@maxwd][c]{\usebox\boxtext@maintext}}%
        \rlap
          {%
            \makebox[\boxtext@maxwd][c]
              {%
                \raisebox
                  {%
                    \dimexpr
                      \ht\boxtext@maintext+\dp\boxtext@toptext
                      +\maintextpad+\toptextpad
                  }
                  {\usebox\boxtext@toptext}%
              }%
          }%
        \rlap
          {%
            \makebox[\boxtext@maxwd][c]
              {%
                \raisebox
                  {%
                    -\dimexpr
                      \dp\boxtext@maintext+\ht\boxtext@bottomtext
                      +\maintextpad+\bottomtextpad
                  }
                  {\usebox\boxtext@bottomtext}%
              }%
          }%
        \rlap{\boxtext@toprule}%
        \rlap{\boxtext@bottomrule}%
        \hskip\boxtext@maxwd
        \llap{\boxtext@toprule}%
        \llap{\boxtext@bottomrule}%
        \boxtext@siderule
        \endgroup
      }%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\boxtext
  {Name xy}
  {\textcolor{red}{2019}}
  {Name}%

\boxtext
  {\textsf{Name xy}}
  {{\sffamily\bfseries\huge\textcolor{red}{2019}}}
  {\textsf{Name}}

\boxtext{Name xy}[5cm]{This is some text that is 5cm wide}{Name}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: haha, ok that works as well ;-)

Comment: @simande and it's only 153 lines of code to create the `\boxtext` macro, so definitely the way to go!