# How do you create a shaded white box with an example theorem heading?

Tags: examples, box

I want to create the example below but I do not know how to do so. It is an Example Theorem around a shaded white frame box. I am open to new suggestions. Thank you for your help! [image: Example Theorem in a shaded white boxx]

Comment: The answers in this question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510533/tikz-box-frame-arround-text-with-interruption could give you some ideas.